# Need to replace a static value in all controllers even in whole project. Is there any way that i can change this value from only a single function?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I have a pre-build project and there is some static value passed in the whole project. Instead of looking in every controller and blade file, I want to change these static values replace to the values from the env file.

**What I tried: **
In the bootstrap folder in the app.php file, I created a function for replacing static values by using str_replace() and call this function in the same file. This is not working.

I don't want to change the static value in the controller, But on the run time.

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The first thing we will do is create a new Laravel application instance
| which serves as the "glue" for all the components of Laravel, and is
| the IoC container for the system binding all of the various parts.
|
*/

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bind Important Interfaces
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we need to bind some important interfaces into the container so
| we will be able to resolve them when needed. The kernels serve the
| incoming requests to this application from both the web and CLI.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Return The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This script returns the application instance. The instance is given to
| the calling script so we can separate the building of the instances
| from the actual running of the application and sending responses.
|
*/


function replaceHello()
{
    str_replace("world","all.","Hello world");
}
replaceHello();

return $app;
```

This function is for replace world from the hello world to hello all in whole project.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: fyi, your function replaces some string, then terminates. It doesn't `echo` or `return` the results. Your IDE's "Replace" function doesn't work?

Comment: Is it only in controller? Or whole laravel folder?

Comment: @AndreHaykal this is for the whole laravel project.

Comment: @brombeer thank you now it's replacing the value...also is this the right approach for this?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the static value that you will change? Is it stored in class property or else?

Comment: @AndreHaykal actually there is an email used in the Mail function in many controllers so I want to replace that email with .env value, is it possible with this approach?

Comment: So you want to rename the mailable classname in the fly?

Comment: @AndreHaykal exactly, I have tried most solutions but nothing is working out.